# How do I update Compass to the latest alpha release?

Tags: rubygems, bundler, compass-sass

I tried installing the latest dev, and it seems to have worked? compass 1.0.0.alpha.18

But in my project, I now have compass 0.12.2 AND compass 1.0.0.alpha BOTH installed as gems. Is this right? It seems wrong, but I don't know how to only use the newer alpha version. What do I have to run or download?

I have a decent understanding of this stuff, but not an expert, so thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's generally no harm in having both versions installed. By default, your project will use the latest version you have. If you want more control over version management you could use tools like [Bundler](http://bundler.io) and [RVM](https://rvm.io/), but it's not required. you can also `gem cleanup` to [remove older gems](http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem_cleanup) — or `gem uninstall compass` and it will ask what version you want to uninstall.